# regex match quantifier for multiple sets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex

`^[^\s-#]+\s?[^\s-#]*[^\s-#]{2,32}#[0-9]{4}$`

Rules:

- format must be STRING#dddd , a string, followed by hashtag, followed by 4 digits
- the string cannot start or end with space or "-" or hashtag
- no double spaces
- the string must be between 2 and 32 chars long

The above regex works. 
The only rule i haven't managed to implement is the last one

Comment: Add `(?=.{2,32}$)` after `^`

Comment: @rv7that doesn't work. i need every char outside of -,# and doublespace

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works, thank you